# Can we submit a spark job from spark itself (may be from another spark program)?

Tags: apache-spark

Can anyone clarify the question asked in one of my interviews to me? It could be that the question itself is wrong, I am not sure. However, I have searched everywhere and could not find anything related to this question. The question is:

> Can we run a spark job from another spark program?

Comment: Use comment section for more questions and/or edit your question to elaborate on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you are right its not make any sense. Like we can run our application by our driver program but its same as like we are run it from any application using spark launcher https://github.com/phalodi/Spark-launcher . Except that we can't run application inside rdd closures because they run on worker nodes so it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we run a spark job from another spark program?

I'd focus on `another` part of the question since the following holds for **any** Spark program:

> Can we run a Spark job from any Spark program?

That means that either there was a follow-up question or some introduction to the one you were asked.

If I were you and heard the question, I'd say *"Yes, indeed!"*

---

A Spark application is in other words a launcher of Spark jobs and the only reason to have a Spark application is to run Spark jobs sequentially or in parallel.

Any Spark application does this and nothing more.

---

A Spark application is a Scala application (when Scala is the programming language) and as such it is possible to run a Spark program from another Spark program (where it makes sense in general sense I put aside as there could be conflicts with multiple `SparkContext`s per one single JVM).

Given the other Spark application is a separate executable jar, you could launch it using [Process](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.11/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) API in Scala (as any other application):

> **scala.sys.process** This package handles the execution of external processes.